# Restrict WCF Service Calls to Regions

Tags: wcf, web-services, security, web, soa

The company I'm working at does not have a great Infrastructure, it is treated as one big network, there is no network segregation. As such when were developing applications we have a TEST/UAT/PROD/DR setup.  I have been developing a suite of services that have been deployed on all the above regions.  How do i make sure that a developer can not call a production web service by accident?  Is there anyway to restrict the service by caller (ie: server name?).

BTW all these services are internal and are not externally available.

Thanks Again for your help.

Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Role based Authorization

[Authorization In WCF-Based Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc948343.aspx)